# SSIS execution report is unreadable (cyrillic symbols in package)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

world.

I have an SQL Server 2016 and a lot of SSIS packages. Now I would like to see the results of SSIS package execution.

To do that I go to "SSIS package store" on server, find my package, right click and select "All reports"- "Standard Reports" - "All executions".

SQL Server shows me execution report, however it's completely unreadable. My package has Russian headers in tasks. That causes report to look like this:

```
ĐģĐ°ŅĐŊĐž ŅĐĩŅĐĩĐŊĐ¸Ņ ŅŅĐ´ŅĐ¸, Đ
```

Is there a way to fix that and show Russian headers in execution report?

thanks in advance,
Gennadiy

Comment: You could try querying the log tables themselves.  This is a good starting point http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/10/17/querying-the-ssis-catalog-here-s-a-handy-query.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have installed last version of SSMS and it helped.